# python: a class instance as a function argument

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm new to python, and I want to use an instance of a class as an argument of a function, like the following codes:

bot.py

```
from Bot import Qhttp, Event
import func

bot = Qhttp()

@bot.on('message')
async def _Msg(event: Event):
    print(event.message)
    await func.dosomething(event)

bot.run(hots='0.0.0.0', port=23456)
```

func.py

```
async def dosomething(event):
    print(event.message)
```

Qhttp is an object that is develop based on Quart, receiving http post information.

`message` is a string in an Event object.

In `async def _Msg(event: Event):`, the string can be printed normally, but in `async def dosomething(event):`, I can't get the string. it prints:

`functools.partial(<bound method Qhttp.call_action of <Bot.Qhttp object at 0xMEMORYADDRESS>>, 'message')`

how can I access the `message` string in `async def dosomething(event):`?

Comment: What is an `Event` object?  It looks like you need to run `print(event.message())` based on the output, but if it works in `_Msg` then there's something else going on here.  Links to documentation would help.

Comment: `@bot.on('message')` `async def _Msg(event: Event):` in here, `Qhttp` receive http post in json format, then the information will be delivered into `Event` object. `Event.message` is a string in the object.

Comment: If `Event` is just a generic object, and `.message` is just a string, then there's something going on that you're not showing in your post.  It's not possible to pass anything as an argument, and have the callee receive something different, without something like descriptors or reflection.

Comment: fk me the function has some other arguments that I put them in wrong order...  fk me I spend 3 days in searching functools partial things...

Comment: In future, posting a full [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) will help both you and those trying to help.  I wasn't able to find your issue, because I couldn't run your code.